# Want to learn about Linux servers and how to operate them?

Tags: linux

I will soon take a dedicated server from a hosting company but I do not know how to operate it. They told me that there will be cPanel and other thing that make it easier. However, I do not know if it is different from shared hosting cPanel?

What I want is some tutorials on how to operate a dedicated server and manage it. Can you help please?

Comment: http://rute.2038bug.com/index.html.gz

Answer (score 3):

There are some good books I can recommend them to you I have read all of these

1) [Red Hat Linux Networking and System administration](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/076453632X)
2) [Red Hat Linux Security and Optimization](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0764547542)
3) [Official Ubuntu Server book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0137081332)
4) [Professional Linux system administration](http://apress.com/book/view/9781430219125)
5) [Orielly Apache Cookbook](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596001919)

As some one mentioned above Rute Users tutorial so once you have a basic understanding then I will recommend you reading these books.Red Hat ones are the best I have read till date.Though a bit old but they rock.

The last one for Apache you will need after you have some experience.Apache is some thing which if not known clearly can be a nightmare.Though it is very simple to operate and understand but having a better understanding of it will not harm.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the administration of a new (GNU/Linux in this case) is not a task to be taken lightly.

You should first try to install linux on a testing platform and follow some guide. As my teacher once said to me, "Linux is for the warned adult". You can do, and probably will (it happened to me a lot of times), screw up a system. Better that you learn this lesson on your testing machine.

If you had work with anything UNIX (BSD, System V, Mac OS, Solaris) you start with almost everything you need because GNU/Linux is a UNIX-ish system with small differences (the base is there).

If you start with a Microsoft background then you will need more time to be sure to know what you're doing. I suggest you to take courses, read books or do tutorials. I don't have any to refer to you because there are plenty of them. You will find what you need.

Comment: In back-up of @Gopoi's post - if you're coming from M$ background you will most certainly screw up at least a dozen times before you start understanding how things really work. When you compile a kernel by yourself - you shall become a "master" :D

Comment: Oh and I know it's a bit late, but thanks for the corrections!!